# smart contract generated transaction

Tags: solidity, signature, smart-contract-wallets, cryptography

As I understand the smart contract is triggered by some action and executes another action based on input.
If I want to send the amount of coin to the target address in case of some action so, the smart contract is involved.

- External action will find a smart contract address in the blockchain.
- Smart Contract will execute by the compiler.

My question is **if I develop a smart contract to send some money to some address in a certain case how these transactions will be validated by miners?** *Because since it is an automatic process signing transaction message by private key is not possible, since the private keys need to keep in a safe zone (device, hardware, etc.)*

**And does miner node put its signature for each execution scenario?**

Answer (score 0):

A smart contract **cannot** initiate a transaction by itself. It always needs to be initialized by an Externally Owned Address, (who has a private key) and miners verify the signature.

Comment: Then how contract account transfer ether to another account ? is it not a transaction? And not required signature?

Comment: It is part of the transaction that was initiated by the user. If you check `tx.origin` at any point in the transaction, it'll be the externally owned address